# R - Multiple plots per page in RStudio

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

I have three precipitation datasets: one observation and two sets of models: raw and bias-corrected. Each set contains five models: `CanESM2, GFDL.ESM2M, MRI.CGCM3, NorESM1.M, inmcm4`.

The following code reproduces my data:

```
obs <- c(8.12903225806452, 4.65483870967742, 4.00967741935484, 2.82903225806452, 
1.02258064516129, 4.94838709677419, 2.03548387096774, 4.56129032258065, 
6.66451612903226, 10.4129032258065, 3.7741935483871, 9.93870967741936)

uncorrected <- structure(list(CanESM2 = c(3.71099209785461, 6.68828105926514, 
4.2675461769104, 4.29092979431152, 6.47999143600464, 6.30958032608032, 
3.28256869316101, 1.06898427009583, 4.01592206954956, 7.88787031173706, 
10.8663206100464, 9.14756298065186), GFDL.ESM2M = c(4.56643295288086, 
8.36136913299561, 4.6934700012207, 4.62750291824341, 6.34791326522827, 
0.916408598423004, 0.111764870584011, 0.570569038391113, 3.05491662025452, 
3.29908037185669, 5.98263263702393, 7.52161026000977), MRI.CGCM3 = c(3.94400858879089, 
2.48861312866211, 0.663281202316284, 0.422377318143845, 1.49548053741455, 
1.8869035243988, 5.35201597213745, 3.94722390174866, 5.0041446685791, 
6.11909627914429, 6.37435054779053, 5.9401068687439), NorESM1.M = c(8.83542060852051, 
8.36209106445312, 3.22844076156616, 2.86131143569946, 2.05858564376831, 
2.39689040184021, 1.06175291538239, 1.03921580314636, 2.49208211898804, 
6.83605766296387, 7.95251750946045, 4.8852391242981), inmcm4 = c(5.88600730895996, 
8.03514385223389, 3.86212635040283, 1.51728367805481, 3.46821308135986, 
1.30993270874023, 0.497318655252457, 0.589299857616425, 1.63358855247498, 
3.61927103996277, 4.99840354919434, 10.5596942901611)), .Names = c("CanESM2", 
"GFDL.ESM2M", "MRI.CGCM3", "NorESM1.M", "inmcm4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))

corrected <- structure(list(CanESM2 = c(4.69295692443848, 6.2362003326416, 
4.48602199554443, 4.21368360519409, 6.02497625350952, 5.94498348236084, 
3.92529225349426, 1.07059073448181, 3.92306709289551, 8.00215721130371, 
10.9688482284546, 9.95723056793213), GFDL.ESM2M = c(6.74847173690796, 
10.7781000137329, 6.89084196090698, 7.5780816078186, 8.96726703643799, 
3.57111501693726, 1.20403492450714, 2.76221370697021, 4.98387718200684, 
5.27927255630493, 8.87845706939697, 9.95864582061768), MRI.CGCM3 = c(5.45173072814941, 
3.37272930145264, 2.20000958442688, 1.12101686000824, 2.67246603965759, 
3.10278224945068, 6.02392053604126, 4.70185708999634, 5.86025190353394, 
6.41299057006836, 7.1956262588501, 7.59840393066406), NorESM1.M = c(9.49540519714355, 
9.88559532165527, 4.86537599563599, 4.56189870834351, 3.85974431037903, 
4.07706260681152, 2.55634951591492, 2.63215637207031, 4.21092081069946, 
7.66422271728516, 8.75070095062256, 5.95497798919678), inmcm4 = c(8.21576976776123, 
11.1972188949585, 6.08181619644165, 3.58428621292114, 5.543297290802, 
3.46666693687439, 1.88991332054138, 1.94812619686127, 3.71879911422729, 
5.70409107208252, 6.85269260406494, 11.8774194717407)), .Names = c("CanESM2", 
"GFDL.ESM2M", "MRI.CGCM3", "NorESM1.M", "inmcm4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

What I need to do is to create qq-plots between models against observations. Therefore, I will have 10 plots (5 models x 2 sets of models).

Then, I need to combine all plots in one single page, in a 5x2 matrix where the rows would be each model (CanESM2, GFDL.ESM2M etc) and the columns would represent each group of models: raw and bias-corrected.

I am almost there. This is what I have done so far:

```
par(mfrow=c(5,2))

for (i in 1:length(names(uncorrected))) {

  # Plot uncorrected vs obs
  qqplot(as.vector(obs), uncorrected[,i], xlim=c(0,14), ylim=c(0,14),
         xlab=expression("Obs. precip." ~ (mm ~ day^{-1})),
         ylab=expression("Mod. precip." ~ (mm ~ day^{-1})))
  abline(0, 1)

  # Then plot corrected vs obs
  qqplot(as.vector(obs), corrected[,i], xlim=c(0,14), ylim=c(0,14),
         xlab=expression("Obs. precip." ~ (mm ~ day^{-1})),
         ylab=expression("Mod. precip." ~ (mm ~ day^{-1})))
  abline(0, 1)

}
```

But I get an error on RStudio: `Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large`

I can get it on standalone R, but the final figure looks really bad, with each plot looking "stretched".

How can I combine all those graphics with an acceptable look within from RStudio?

Comment: what happens when you change the `mar` argument to the `par` graphics function to make the margins smaller?

Comment: have you tried the multiplot function yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of your problem is `mar` argument is big relatively to plot window size as @shayaa & @Vandenman said. Here is a set of `par()` arguments I use with multiplots. The problem of ylab cut is solved by changing height of Rstudio's plot window or output option.

```
par.old <- par(no.readonly=T)    # save old par

par( mfrow = c(5, 2), mar = c(3, 3, 0.5, 0.5), tcl = -0.3, mgp = c(1.7, 0.4, 0) )

for (i in 1:length(names(uncorrected))) {
  # Plot uncorrected vs obs
  qqplot(as.vector(obs), uncorrected[,i], xlim=c(0,14), ylim=c(0,14),
         xlab=expression("Obs. precip." ~ (mm ~ day^{-1})),
         ylab=expression("Mod. precip." ~ (mm ~ day^{-1})))
  abline(0, 1)
  # Then plot corrected vs obs
  qqplot(as.vector(obs), corrected[,i], xlim=c(0,14), ylim=c(0,14),
         xlab=expression("Obs. precip." ~ (mm ~ day^{-1})),
         ylab=expression("Mod. precip." ~ (mm ~ day^{-1})))
  abline(0, 1)
}

par(par.old)    # read old par  (not necessary)
```

If xlab and ylab are common to plots, you can save space by writing xlab and ylab only once at outer margins.

```
par( mfrow = c(5, 2), mar = c(1.2, 1.2, 0.5, 0.5), tcl = -0.3, mgp = c(1.7, 0.4, 0), 
     oma = c(2.5, 2.5, 0, 0) )

for (i in 1:length(names(uncorrected))) {
  # Plot uncorrected vs obs
  qqplot(as.vector(obs), uncorrected[,i], xlim=c(0,14), ylim=c(0,14), ann=F)
  abline(0, 1)
  # Then plot corrected vs obs
  qqplot(as.vector(obs), corrected[,i], xlim=c(0,14), ylim=c(0,14), ann=F)
  abline(0, 1)
}

mtext(side=1, expression("Obs. precip." ~ (mm ~ day^{-1})), outer=T, line=1.1)   
mtext(side=2, expression("Mod. precip." ~ (mm ~ day^{-1})), outer=T, line=0.6)
```

[image][image]

#### [EDITED]

I don't think you need to use layout() unless you want a complex split.

```
par(mfrow = c(3, 4),  mar = c(1.2, 1.2, 0.5, 0.5), tcl = -0.3, mgp = c(1.7, 0.4, 0), 
    oma = c(2.5, 2.5, 0, 0) )

for (i in 1:length(names(uncorrected))) {
  qqplot(as.vector(obs), uncorrected[,i], xlim=c(0,14), ylim=c(0,14), ann=F)
  abline(0, 1)
  legend("topleft", paste0("uncorrected",i), bty="n")  # example
  qqplot(as.vector(obs), corrected[,i], xlim=c(0,14), ylim=c(0,14), ann=F)
  abline(0, 1)
  legend("topleft", paste0("corrected", i), bty="n")   # example
}
for(i in 1:2) plot(0, type="n", ann=F, axes=F) # make two blank graphs

mtext(side=1, expression("Obs. precip." ~ (mm ~ day^{-1})), outer=T, line=1.1)
mtext(side=2, expression("Mod. precip." ~ (mm ~ day^{-1})), outer=T, line=0.6)
```

If you want to use layout(), it is better to use the same `par()` arguments without `mfrow()`. (below code is equivalent to above code)

```
m <- matrix(c(1:10, 0, 0), byrow=T, ncol=4)
layout(m)

par( mar = c(1.2, 1.2, 0.5, 0.5), tcl = -0.3, mgp = c(1.7, 0.4, 0), 
     oma = c(2.5, 2.5, 0, 0) )

for (i in 1:length(names(uncorrected))) {
  qqplot(as.vector(obs), uncorrected[,i], xlim=c(0,14), ylim=c(0,14), ann=F)
  abline(0, 1)
  legend("topleft", paste0("uncorrected",i), bty="n")  # example
  qqplot(as.vector(obs), corrected[,i], xlim=c(0,14), ylim=c(0,14), ann=F)
  abline(0, 1)
  legend("topleft", paste0("corrected", i), bty="n")   # example
}

mtext(side=1, expression("Obs. precip." ~ (mm ~ day^{-1})), outer=T, line=1.1)   
mtext(side=2, expression("Mod. precip." ~ (mm ~ day^{-1})), outer=T, line=0.6)
```

And if you want to repeat the NO.9 & 10 graphs, you should change `for()` argument (i.e., `for ( i in c(1:5, 5) )`)  (and if use `layout()`, `m <- matrix(c(1:12), byrow=T, ncol=4)`. In `layout()`, same number mean docking)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works! I found out that the resulting figure is too "long" to be inserted in a word document, for example. Instead, I want to organize a matrix layout to plot them. I am trying to do something like `m <- cbind(c(1,5,9), c(2,6,10), c(3,7,9), c(4,8,10)); layout(m)`, but the results are poor again. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: By the way, very nice job on the common axis labels!

Comment: This looks really cool, thank you! Just one more thing: what if I need to add a legend in each plot? I tried `legend("topleft", names(un.df[i]), bty="n")` within the loop, after each plot command, to no avail...

Comment: You need to put a `legend()` code after each plot, `qqplot()`. I edited to add legends.

Answer (score 1):

`Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large` Can be a rather computer dependent error. If you simply resize the plotwindow in Rstudio to be as large as possible and then rerun the code, does it still occur? If yes, it's likely Rstudio that cannot show the plot on your machine. You can workaround this by calling `x11()` before the plot to open a new window for the plot (like base R does), or you can use something like:

```
pdf('test.pdf')
# make plots
dev.off()
```

Which creates a pdf document containing the plots.